# Multiplication in a range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, segment-tree, rmq

I have an array to 10 numbers supprse A[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
and I have to compute the multiplication of numbers in a particular range but not getting correct answer, I am using segment tree and dont know how to use query operation
Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define m 1000000000
#define MAX 100010

typedef unsigned long long ull;
ull a[MAX];
ull tree[4*MAX];

void build_tree(int n,int b,int e){
    if(b>e)return ;
    else if(b==e){
        tree[n] = a[b];
        return ;
    }
    build_tree(n*2,b,(b+e)/2);
    build_tree(n*2+1,(b+e)/2+1,e);
    tree[n] =( tree[n*2]%m * tree[n*2 + 1]%m )%m;
}


ull query(int index, int ss, int se, int qs, int qe)
  {
      ull p1, p2,p;
      if (qs > se || qe < ss)
          return -1;

      if (ss >= qs && se <= qe)
          return tree[index];
      p1 = query(2 * index, ss, (ss + se) / 2, qs, qe);
      p2 = query(2 * index + 1, (ss + se) / 2 + 1, se,qs, qe);
      printf("\np1 = %d   p2 = %d",p1,p2);
      p=(tree[p1]%m*tree[p2]%m)%m;
      return p;

}
int main(){
    int n,i,query_start,query_end,segment_start,segment_end,index;
    ull value;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
    build_tree(1,0,n-1);
    query_start=1;
    query_end=2;
    segment_start=0;
    segment_end = n-1;
    index=1;
    printf("Tree Formed :-\n");
    for(i=0;i<n*4;i++)
          printf("%d  ",tree[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    value=query(index,segment_start,segment_end,query_start,query_end);
    printf("\nvalue = %lld\n",value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to update the tree (i.e. can the values in the array change)? If not, you don't need a segment tree just for queries.

Comment: @MAK if array is very large and number of queries is large then just for queries also seg-tree can be used as far as i know

Comment: @sashasami: I didn't say segment tree can't be used. What I'm saying is, you can do it a lot simpler than using a segment tree, if there are no updates.

Comment: @MAK ok. sir could you tell a faster way because many a times I use it without thinking even when no updates are there.

Comment: @sashasami: I've posted an answer explaining my idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly off topic, but posting this mainly as a response to sasha sami. This still works as an alternate idea to solve the OP's problem.

If there are no queries, we don't really need to use a segment tree. The idea is to keep another array containing the cumulative products of the values in the input array.

So, if the input array is

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

The corresponding product array will be:

```
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

Now, we know the product of all elements [0, i] for any index i. To get the product between indices i and j, we can just get the product for [0, j] and [0, i] and use that to get our answer. The product for [i, j] is actually [0, j] / [0, i - 1]. To avoid specially handling the case where i = 0 we can also rewrite it as [0, j] / [0, i] * element at i.

Code (in Python):

```
#! /usr/bin/python


def build_products_array(array):
  ret = [0 for i in xrange(len(array))]
  ret[0] = array[0]
  last_value = 1 if array[0] else array[0]
  for i in xrange(1, len(array)):
    if array[i]:
      ret[i] = last_value * array[i]
      last_value = ret[i]
    else:
      ret[i] = last_value
  return ret


def build_zero_array(array):
  ret = [0 for i in xrange(len(array))]
  ret[0] = 0 if array[i] else 1
  for i in xrange(1, len(array)):
    ret[i] = ret[i - 1] + (0 if array[i] else 1)
  return ret


def check_zeros(zero_array, array, i, j):
  return zero_array[j] - zero_array[i] + (0 if array[i] else 1)


def query(products, zero_array, array, start, end):
  if check_zeros(zero_array, array, start, end):
    return 0
  else:
    return products[end] / products[start] * array[start]


def main():
  array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  products = build_products_array(array)
  zeros = build_zero_array(array)
  for i in xrange(len(array)):
    for j in xrange(i, len(array)):
      print "Querying [%d, %d]: %d\n" % (i, j, query(products, zeros, array, i, j))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The thing to watch out for is overflows because the cumulative products can get quite big, even if the answers to the queries are guaranteed to be small enough. The above code it in Python, so there's not fear of overflows there, but in C++ you might want to use bignums. Its also handy if you need to find the products modulo some number - in which case overflow is not an issue.

This approach will also work for finding the sum of a range of numbers, or any operation for which an inverse operation also exists (e.g. for sum the inverse is subtraction, for products the inverse is division). It wouldn't work for operations like max or min.

This takes O(n) to build the initial product array, and each query is O(1). So this is actually faster than segment tree (which queries in O(log n) ).

EDIT:
Updated the code to handle zeros in the input. We keep another array keeping the total count of 0s at each index. For each query we check that array to see if there are any zeros in that range (as before, knowing the count for [0, i] and [0, j], we can figure out the count for [i, j])). If there are, the answer to that query must be 0. Otherwise we return the product.

Comment: if suppose the array doesn't contain continuous number, suppose array={1,7,9,4,10}.. will this process work ?
question doesn't contain continuous numbers in array and there are huge number of queries

Comment: @avinashse: The actual values in the array do not matter. The number of queries being huge is also not a problem. As I said in my answer, this is O(1) per query - it is actually *faster* than segtree.

Comment: hmmm got your point, thank you :) but I have a question..is it possible that product[start]=0 for any case, if suppose it is zero then what will that query function return ?

Comment: @avinashe: You're right. Actually, having a value of 0 anywhere in the array would make this solution fail. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: any other possible solution if there is any 0 in array ?

Comment: I am just trying to rebuild build_product_array() for handling zero case

Comment: @avinashse: Just off the top off my head: ignore 0s in build_product_array. Keep the position of the zeros in another array. For each query find the product and then check if there are any zeros in that range. If there are zeros the answer is 0 otherwise output the product. Checking for 0s can be easily done in O(log n) at least using binary search.

Comment: yes I am doing that only MAK :) but I cant simply ignore 0s in build_arrar_product() because `ret[i] = ret[i - 1] * array[i]` if ret[i-1] = 0 then if I ignore it then there will be problem

Comment: @avinashse: Instead of using ret[i - 1], keep another variable called last_value, which gets every time unless its a 0. I have to go away for a while, I'll update my answer when I come back.

Comment: thank u for the reply.. One more thing, what I have to do is, along with start and end in query() I am passing one more parameter mod which I have to do like this : `((products[end] / products[start])%mod * array[start]%mod)%mod`  but it is showing SIGFPE error, i thaught it is due to division by 0, but I am wrong, testcases doesn't contain zero in array, so why this SIGFPE is coming, please guide me in this direction :(

Comment: If you are doing operations modulo some number, division won't work. You need to find the modular inverse for that. So instead of a / b, you have to do (a * modular_inverse(b, mod)) % mod. Look up wikipedia for how to find the modular inverse of a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (qs > se || qe < ss)
      return -1;
```

There is a bug in the if statement used in the code. The function should return 1 instead of -1 if the above condition comes across. The rest of the query function seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following template for segment tree its general:

```
/*The query function to get maximum in a range*/
function get_max(cur_node, i, j) {
i = max(i, cur_node.i)
j = min(j, cur_node.j)
if (i > j) return -infinity
if (i == cur_node.i and j == cur_node.j) return cur_node.max
res = max(get_max(cur_node.left_child, i, j), get_max(cur_node.right_child, i, j))
res += cur_node.add
return res
}

/* update function which you don't need in this case*/
function update(cur_node, i, j, a) {
i = max(i, cur_node.i)
j = min(j, cur_node.j)
if (i > j) return
if (i == cur_node.i and j == cur_node.j) {
  cur_node.add += a
  cur_node.max += a
  return
}
update(cur_node.left_child, i, j, a)
update(cur_node.right_child, i, j, a)
cur_node.max = max(cur_node.left_child.max, cur_node.right_child.max) + cur_node.add
}
```

Comment: hmmm thank you for the reply, i designed my code from the template, but still not getting correct outout, please check in my code..

Answer (score 0):

for multiplication in a query range using segment tree, You have to 'return 1' in the `if(b>e)` condition inside the `build_tree` method AND also in the `if (qs > se || qe < ss)` inside the  `ull query` method AND add some conditions as below in your case.

```
int build_tree(int n,int b,int e){
    if(b>e)return 1;
    else if(b==e){
        tree[n] = a[b];
        return tree[n];
    }
    build_tree(n*2,b,(b+e)/2);
    build_tree(n*2+1,(b+e)/2+1,e);
    tree[n] =( tree[n*2]%m * tree[n*2 + 1]%m )%m;
}


ull query(int index, int ss, int se, int qs, int qe)
  {
      ull p1, p2,p;
      if (qs<= ss && qe>= se)
        {
            return tree[index];
        }
      if (qs > se || qe < ss)
          return 1;

      if (ss >= qs && se <= qe)
          return tree[index];
      p1 = query(2 * index, ss, (ss + se) / 2, qs, qe);
      p2 = query(2 * index + 1, (ss + se) / 2 + 1, se,qs, qe);
      printf("\np1 = %d   p2 = %d",p1,p2);
      p=(tree[p1]%m*tree[p2]%m)%m;
      return p;

}
```

Thanks.